# Runtime error when tapping a UITextField

Tags: ios, swift

I run into an error whenever I tapped a textfield. im not able to understand the meaning. this happen when I try to load a viewController when the user tap a textfieldfield.

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        if textField == self.location {

            let vc = RquestDetailViewController()

            self.show(vc, sender: nil)
        }
        return false
}
```

error here

```
attribute, Arg[1] = [Closure Propagated : reabstraction thunk helper from @callee_owned (@unowned Swift.UnsafeBufferPointer<Swift.UInt8>) -> () to @callee_owned (@unowned Swift.UnsafeBufferPointer<Swift.UInt8>) -> (@out ()), Argument Types : [@callee_owned (@unowned Swift.UnsafeBufferPointer<Swift.UInt8>) -> ()]> of generic specialization <preserving fragile attribute, ()> of Swift.StaticString.withUTF8Buffer <A> ((Swift.UnsafeBufferPointer<Swift.UInt8>) -> A) -> A
->  0x102358014 <+120>: brk    #0x1
```

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to do when the textField is tapped ?

Comment: is self.location is of UITextField type?

Comment: are you using storyboard?

Comment: my guess that your problem is not in this delegate method. its with the view controller you are trying to show.

Answer (score 1):

The function `textFieldShouldBeginEditing` is intended for checking preconditions before editing. You missuse it for view changes. This may cause some internal runtime errors in the textfield delegate flow.

Try to use a `UIButton` or a `UILabel & UITapGestureRecognizer` instead.

Comment: sry I do that in textfield didbeginediting but I set the input view for the textfield to nil. works fine with me. My guess is textFieldShouldBeginEditing is good too.

Comment: It's your choice, but I don't wanna use your code ;) - See it from caller perspective. I ask you "Can I input text" and instead of telling me yes or no you do something completely unexpected for me.

Comment: true. It could be bad as a UX. but from a technical point of view it perfectly ok.